# Preserve image size after encryption in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, encryption, image-size

I am trying to encrypt an image in MATLAB using pixel confusion and diffusion. So the code changes the position of the pixel and the changes the pixel grayscale value. The problem is that the encrypted image I get is 2-3 times bigger than the original image. I cannot understand why this is happening! Any help will be appreciated.

Pedro

Comment: Could you provide the relevant code?

Comment: My guess would be that you change the position to a position that may be outside the original area. But then again, it is impossible to answer this question without more information.

Answer (score 0):

An encrypted image is likely to be far less compressible than the original because an encrypted image is more 'random' than the original.  Is the image in a compressed format, such as JPEG?  If so then you will very probably not be able to avoid the problem.

A non-compressed image format, like BMP, should give you the same file size which may be a possible solution.

There are encryption methods that do not increase file size, such as CTR mode, but they may well not be displayable as an image since the necessary file format information is also encrypted.  You could store the encrypted file somewhere and put up a place holder: "Image encrypted" in its place.